# Error after deploy app with amplify and monorepo

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, monorepo, aws-amplify

I'm getting a **403** error in my application whenever I implement a new version in the amplifier and it only works again if I clear the site cache.

path that returns **403** status:
***/vendor.js***

I'm using quasar.js for my frontend.

I already checked my **amplify.yml** file and everything is ok, i don't know what it could be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered the problem...

Taking a closer look at what was running in the build, i found that the amplifier can't cache the cache when I did a new deployment, due to the ***maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes*** limit, so in my quasar application i set the limit and it as needed and that's it, solved!